# How can spring boot application instances be packaged in testcontainers

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

1. there are several instances of applications that interact with each other (microservices)
2. There are docker images of these spring boot apps
3. Is it possible to use these docker images in test container to deploy in tests and how is it possible to do this

There is no need to take into account the time to work and initialization of such tests, this is not the main thing in this situation.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://www.testcontainers.org/features/creating_images/

Comment: I already have a docker image. It is in the docker registry. But, Thank you.  This will also come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testcontainers offers GenericContainer which allow you to use images in the registry. For example, let's say you have a image for your service called `myorganization/greetings-service:2.0.0` which listen request in the port 8080. Then you can use:

```
GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer("myorganization/greetings-service:2.0.0")
           .withExposedPort(8080)
           .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/"));
```

and later you can get the host and port using `container.getHost()` and `container.getMappedPort(8080)`.

Hope this can help you